# Log Shipping - Secondary Database(s) - Which recovery model?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, recovery-model

In Log shipping configuration - the primary database must be either in Full or Bulk-Logged recovery model. However, is there any requirement of recovery model of the secondary database?

Example: Assuming both primary and secondary databases are in full recovery model, if there is a failover and the secondary becomes the new primary, we could change the db recovery model.

Also refer to: https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2832586&seqNum=3 and search for "Log shipped databases have to use the full recovery model." - is this correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recovery model for the secondary will be the same as the primary database, because you're backing up the primary, restoring it on the secondary node using NORECOVERY/STANDBY, and then restoring subsequent log files to it.

In a log shipping configuration, you cannot make changes to the secondary database. If you could, then the databases would be out of sync, defeating the purpose of log shipping as a DR solution.

Edit: The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) is fairly comprehensive regarding the basics of log shipping and the requirements for it.